# How do SE sites get special icons?

Tags: support, beta-sites, favicon

How does an SE site get a special icon?  Is that only done internally by SE staffers?  Can it be done on a site's meta?  Can I get rep by designing one?

I have some obvious icons for sites that are still "generic" like Astronomy ("A") and Chemistry ("Ch").  How can I submit them for consideration or use?

Comment: When you say "special icon", what _exactly_ do you mean? The whole site design? The favicon? Something else? Any examples of sites that have such an icon versus those that don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astronomy - at the time of writing - is still a beta site. Beta sites have a generic template and the icon you mention. Once a site graduates out of the beta stage, it will get its own lovely design.

Comment: Ah ha, sure enough: I'm now realizing that all the "generic" sites I use are betas!